# Inserting multiple rows into table with counter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that can select for me the positions of all the shows in my database based on ranking. I need to insert them into a "Ranking history" table that looks like this:

```
Table:Ranking_History
Ranking_id    Show_id   Date   Position
1               3                  1
2               18                 2  
3               2                  3
```

The thing is currently, I am getting all the positions through PHP and then inserting it into my database. Something like this:

```
$positions = Show::get_positions();
$pos = 1;
foreach ($positions as $key=>$val) {
    INSERT INTO ranking_history (show_id, date, position) VALUES ('$val', CURDATE(), '$pos')
    $pos++;
}
```

Is there a way I can avoid the overhead lag from running multiple queries and insert this into one single query?

Something like a `INSERT...SELECT` statement, but there needs to be some sort of counter that can keep track of the current "row". Is the overhead cost even that important to consider in this case (I'm inserting about 6000 rows every day). I'm fairly certain that it needs to be done through a stored procedure, but am pretty new to MySQL in that category.

Comment: If you do this at one time then wrap the foreach in a transaction and commit at the end. I suspect it will run a lot faster. I suggest you do not change the query. Time how long it takes to run. Then you can decide whether to change to 'one query' as suggested. If you convert it to a 'prepared query' and use 'bind and 'execute' then it will be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

an insert can take many sets of values, so create them first, and then run the single insert

```
    $values='';
    foreach ($positions as $key=>$val) {
        $values .= "('$val', CURDATE(), '$pos'),";
        $pos++;
    }

    $values=rtrim($values,','); //remove left over comma

    $q="INSERT INTO ranking_history (show_id, date, position) VALUES ".$values;

//run $q
```